# How do I convert the .place() method in python to java?

Tags: python, java, windows, frame

I am trying to convert my Python Code to Java. I need a GUI that is similar to python where I can use `widgetname.place(x,y)` to place objects anywhere I want in the window. I want to be able to specify where the object is placed in the window. I have tried `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `BoxLayout` and `FlowLayout`. None of those are allowing me to secify x and y coordinates to place my objects(text fields, labels, buttons) where ever I want. I need to be able to specify where the object goes on the screen using x and y coordinates.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) that gives a concise example on positioning widgets absolutely.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done setting your `LayoutManager` to `null`, but it's highly discouraged precisely because it annihilates the goal of layouts, which is to be able to have good-looking frames, regardless of the look and feel, screen resolution, etc.

You'd better [learn how to use layout managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), because that's the good way to design a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you do start using LayoutManagers I recommend using TableLayout because it far easier and more powerful than GridBagLayout.

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/

Hopefully your need to do absolute positioning is relatively small because it's not flexible should the user resize the window, and your components need to change their size.  If you are trying to build a component that renders to X,Y to draw graphics you can subclass JComponent and override paint().